# Initial Backup stopped sending data

Tags: backup, azure

I want to use the azure online backup to save some 200 gb of data. As expected (the bandwith is quite low), the process ran for a few days. However, I could see the progress in the Backup Usage tile in the dashboard as the number went up everday. For the past few days, I noticed no more progress there and also no upload network traffic on the server.

[image]

Today, I took a closer look on the Backup Jobs page and noticed that there are three jobs running. I don't know, if this has anything to do with initial backup stopping to send data to the azure vault.

Has anybody an idea, what is wrong here?

[image]

UPDATE - errlog:

```
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  failoverreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(180) [0000000019672270]          NORMAL  FailoverReplicationEndpointProvider::QueryInterface called with interface 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000046
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  failoverreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(210) [0000000019672270]          WARNING FailoverReplicationEndpointProvider::QueryInterface called with unknown interface 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000046
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  failoverreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(180) [0000000019672270]          NORMAL  FailoverReplicationEndpointProvider::QueryInterface called with interface 00000000-0000-0000-c000-000000000046
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  mtreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(199)   [000000001966FF60]          NORMAL  MTReplicationEndpointProvider::QueryInterface called with interface 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000046
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  mtreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(239)   [000000001966FF60]          WARNING MTReplicationEndpointProvider::QueryInterface called with unknown interface 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000046
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  mtreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(199)   [000000001966FF60]          NORMAL  MTReplicationEndpointProvider::QueryInterface called with interface 00000000-0000-0000-c000-000000000046
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  mtreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(230)   [000000001966FF60]          NORMAL  QueryInterface called for IUnknown interface
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  failoverreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(81)  [0000000019672270]          NORMAL  CFailoverReplicationEndpointProviderWrapper:~CFailoverReplicationEndpointProviderWrapper: 0, 0000000019672270
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  mtreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(88)    [000000001966FF60]          NORMAL  CMTReplicationEndpointProviderWrapper:~CMTReplicationEndpointProviderWrapper: 0, 000000001966FF60
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    83  mtreplicationendpointproviderwrapper.cpp(99)    [000000001966FF60]          NORMAL  DeleteCriticalSection object ptr 000000001966FF80
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    71  service.cpp(767)                NORMAL  Deregistered CBEngine COM server successfully
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    71  engine.cpp(1247)    [00007FFC35925340]          NORMAL  Async status - No async operation running to abort
0C88    1D70    05/28   14:39:57.989    22  genericthreadpool.cpp(686)  [000000001A7D5218]          NORMAL  CGenericThreadPool: Waiting for threads to exit
0C88    01DC    05/28   14:39:59.801    71  dscontext.cpp(169)  [000000001A7A7980]  AEB3E5C7-7A4C-46D8-9973-2FD693668D9B        NORMAL  Last completed state for Ds Id (87963066833904) is 5
0C88    1470    05/28   14:40:00.020    03  timer.cpp(513)  [000000001BD4F140]          ACTIVITY    Shutting down timer thread.
0C88    01DC    05/28   14:40:01.864    22  watsonintegration.cpp(74)       AEB3E5C7-7A4C-46D8-9973-2FD693668D9B        NORMAL  Inside Watson Handler
0C88    01DC    05/28   14:40:01.864    22  watsonintegration.cpp(117)      AEB3E5C7-7A4C-46D8-9973-2FD693668D9B        CRITICAL    Raising Watson for process
```

Comment: any feedback from the tool?

Comment: Actually, I found in the log files, that the cbengine crashed. After I restarted the service, it also crashed. I've restarted the server and now it is running again. I'll update the question with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was "solved" by restarting the backup everytime it chrashed until the upload was finished.